# Meteor : create a search (filter) without using autopublish

Tags: meteor

I have a search facility in my project and I need to be able to publish results without using *autopublish*.

html

```
<template name="search">
  <form  id="searchform">
    <input type="text"  id="kategori" placeholder="Sila masukkan maklumat carian."/>
    <button>Carian</button>
  </form>
  <hr/>
  <h3>Maklumat</h3>
  <ol>
    {{#each profil}}
      <li>{{jenama}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ol>
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.search.events({
  "submit #searchform": function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set("kategori", e.target.text.value);
  }
});

Template.search.helpers({
  profil: function() {
    return Profil.find({
      kategori: Session.get('kategori'),
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *subscribe* to a filtered publication:

client:

```
Template.search.events({
  "submit #searchform": function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set("kategori", e.target.text.value);
    Meteor.subscribe('profiles',Session.get('kategori'));
  }
});
```

server:

```
Meteor.publish('profiles',function(kategori){
  return Profil.find({ kategori: kategori });
});
```

If you don't have any other subscriptions to the same collection you can also simplify your helper to:

```
Template.search.helpers({
    profil: function() {
      return Profil.find();
    }
});
```

Since the set of documents will be defined by your publication.

In practice though you usually use the same search in your helper as you do in the publication just to avoid documents from other publications showing up.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. How about iron router? I need put some data function or not.

Comment: Not necessarily, unless you make search a route with a parameter.